# Arcpy creating Polyline from dictionary values

Tags: arcpy, geometry, csv, line, array

I am attempting to do the final project for the open source Penn state class https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/144. The task is to parse a CSV file containing rhino coordinates and create a polyline.
I have written code that I believe should work but nothing gets created in the feature class

```
import csv
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
file = 'C:\RhinoObservations.csv'
geodb = "C:\rhinotracks.gdb"
earthq = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(geodb,"Rhino","POLYLINE",'','',"ENABLED",4326)
arcpy.AddField_management(earthq,"NAME","TEXT")
rhino = {}
with open(file, 'rb') as csvv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvv)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Rhino'] not in rhino:
            rhino[row['Rhino']] = []
        rhino[row['Rhino']].append((float(row['X']),float(row['Y'])))
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(earthq,("NAME","SHAPE@XY")) as cur:
    for k,v in rhino.items():
        print k,v
        array = arcpy.Array()
        for coords in v:
            array.add(arcpy.Point(float(coords[0]),float(coords[1])))
        line = arcpy.Polyline(array,4326)
        row2 = (k,line)
        cur.insertRow(row2)
```

the script throws no error and create a feature class of the rhinos names but there are no polylines

[image]

I am using this post as a reference [Creating arrays and polylines from dictionary using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184354/creating-arrays-and-polylines-from-dictionary-using-arcpy/184373#184373)

when I print k,v the rhinos name has the correct XY pairs stored in their correct tuples. I do not know why there is no polyline showing up
this is the output for the Rhino Meredith when I print k,v. Tuple in a list

```
Meredith [(26.97808, -19.11016), (26.97768, -19.11153), (26.97551, -19.11269), (26.97657, -19.11343), (26.97607, -19.11448), (26.97434, -19.11438), (26.97311, -19.11301), (26.97378, -19.11269), (26.97412, -19.11175), (26.97479, -19.11085)]
```

Comment: Can you include a copy/paste of the printed XY pairs?

Comment: There was another similar question here recently - reason for no lines being produced was that the XY were pretty much right on top of each other, which looks like might be the issue for you.  Do a search for similar recent questions

Comment: i dont think that would be the issue...they give this assignment for a class and show the output picture

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206857/update-cursor-to-polyline-creates-records-with-missing-geometry

Comment: Why SHAPE@XY, what is happening when you use SHAPE@ in InsertCursor?

Comment: @FelixIP that was it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this page:  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm#C_GUID-FC2C3085-2C89-4CDB-985B-DFE78118B603

This has a code sample for creating a polyline.

Try this instead (changed the polyline creation and SHAPE field):

```
import csv
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
file = 'C:\RhinoObservations.csv'
geodb = "C:\rhinotracks.gdb"
earthq = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(geodb,"Rhino","POLYLINE",'','',"ENABLED",4326)
arcpy.AddField_management(earthq,"NAME","TEXT")
rhino = {}
with open(file, 'rb') as csvv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvv)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Rhino'] not in rhino:
            rhino[row['Rhino']] = []
        rhino[row['Rhino']].append((row['X'],row['Y']))
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(earthq,("NAME","SHAPE@")) as cur:
    for k,v in rhino.items():
        print k,v
        line = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in v]))
        row2 = (k,line)
        cur.insertRow(row2)
```

You were using the SHAPE@XY token.  This is the token for the feature's centroid.  For the feature's geometry, you need to use the SHAPE@ token.

Comment: weird I was initially using the SHAPE@ token and it wasnt working but it just worked

Comment: were you testing in the python window?  It stores everything you do in memory, so when you get your code right, make sure to restart arc to clear everything from memory and retest.

Comment: Nope standalone script. I probably had another error or something